# preventing refresh when clicking on the current page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm new to asp.net MVC4.

I'm implementing a navigation bar in my website.

I'd like to prevent refresh when clicking the current page in the nav bar.

**UPDATE**
I'm using Razor for the navigation bar:

```
<ul>

@Html.ActionLink("FEATURE_1_URL","FEATURE_1_URL","Home")
@Html.ActionLink("FEATURE_2_URL","FEATURE_2_URL","Home")
@Html.ActionLink("FEATURE_4_URL","FEATURE_4_URL","Home")
</ul>
```

How can I accomplish it?

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: It's a general question, I need to implement this feature:
If you have Home and About in Navigation and you click on Home you will get the Home page but the next time you'll click on it and you're I don't want it to send another request to the server.
do you know where can I find tutorials for such a thing?

Comment: Just so I understand correctly, if you are on the home page (for example) and click the home page link, you don't want the page to refresh, right? If so, you have a few options. One might be to wrap that Html.Link in an 'if' statement and render a label instead of a link if on the same page. Another is dynamically add a "#" as the URL instead of the real URL. I am not aware of a "built in" way to do this however, you'll need to roll your own method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the given solutions Page will be refreshed but will reduce server call and  will not call action  again and again.

In MVC4 one of best way you can achieve this purpose it by using Caching

```
[OutputCache(Duration=30)]
public ActionResult FEATURE_1_URL(){}
```

so by specifying time it will store your result in caching so when you click next time ActionLink it will give you result from Caching data as per duration time and it will reduce request to the server.

This can be useful at least for fast response

Comment: I don't think this is the best solution as it is redundantly making a server call. The solution for this should be handled at the client side not server side. I posted my perspective on the solution.

Answer (score 1):

use jquery

```
$('.btnCurrent').on('click', function(e){
    //Determine page using hidden field or something like that
    if(page == currentPage){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: add a class to your actionlink add , new { @class = "btnCurrent" } then you can use this jquery on it

Comment: Yes that is a good suggestion... Basically when you click on any menu item and reloads the page, add a class to the respective menu item. and on the menu nav click check if it is of that class if so ignore.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what I did was create a @helper to build my menu items, you just have to pass to your model what menu item is currently active in some way and when building that item, set href to #. This can be done with javascript/jquery as well.

here was my @helper method:

```
@helper MenuItemDesigner(string MenuItemName, bool hasAccess, string view, string controller, string areaName, MenuItems.Name menuItem, string       glyphicon, string badge)
 {
 if (hasAccess)
 {
     <a 
     @if (Model.ActiveMenuItem == menuItem)
     {
         <text>id = "@menuItem" href="#"</text>
        @Html.Raw("class= 'list-group-item active'");
     }
     else
     {
         <text>id = "@menuItem" href="@Url.Action(view, controller, new { Area = areaName })"</text>
        @Html.Raw("class= 'list-group-item'");
     }
     ><span class="@glyphicon"></span> @MenuItemName <span class="badge" data-val="0" style="display:none">@badge</span>
     </a>
 }
}
```

Clearly not all of this will apply to every scenario but this can be used as a reference. The important part is just knowing the currently active menu item and setting its href="#" however you need to do that.